# Call my own cellForRowAtIndexPath for PSMultiValueSpecifier cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, inappsettingskit

Using InAppSettingsKit (2.8 branch), how should I implement my own cellForRowAtIndexPath for that kind of setting's type (PSMultiValueSpecifier) ?

```
    <dict>
        <key>DefaultValue</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>theme</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Theme</string>
        <key>Titles</key>
        <array>
            <string>Light</string>
            <string>Dark</string>
        </array>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSMultiValueSpecifier</string>
        <key>Values</key>
        <array>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

I need to reconfigure all the cell to apply the current theme but I can't find a way to subclass (or provide the name of a subclass) to the IASKSpecifierValuesViewController  used to display the different choices on setting of type "PSMultiValueSpecifier"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to accomplish this is by subclassing `IASKSpecifierValuesViewController` and using your subclass as a [custom view controller](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit#custom-viewcontrollers). Of course you have to assign the `currentSpecifier`, `settingsReader` and `settingsStore` when the user selects the custom child pane by implementing the delegate method `settingsViewController:tableView:didSelectCustomViewSpecifier:`. Take a look at `IASKAppSettingsViewController.m:711-718` to see what needs to be done.

Comment: Damn, I should have find this on my own, thank you very much ! (and my apologies for the unnecessary github issue)